# Salesforce Marketing Cloud File Organization

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, content-builder, organization

I'm trying to think if there is anything in SFMC where if I start moving things around and folders around, it could break existing automated emails. I inherited a SFMC platform that is chaos. While it is just annoying on the Content Side, at least I can search there. But with Data Extensions, trying to find them is difficult. I would like to get my folder structures more manageable, both for content and data. There might even be folders that are renamed, but not Content Block names or Data Extension names, just folders. I don't think anything references absolute paths that might break something if I do this, but I would love to get a second opinion just to confirm before I start and then find stuff breaking.

Comment: ContentBlockByName can use paths https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/contentblockbyname.html. You'll frequently see it used on highly dynamic multi-lingual comms where you build the path to the content to render using AMPScript. I can't think of much else that does.

Comment: Only other change that might cause potential issues if not done correctly is moving shared to 'local' or vice versa. But that one is fairly obvious...

Comment: @Gortonington, note taken. Thanks.

Comment: @Macca, We use ContentBlockByName or ContentBlockByID frequently. But as long as those names of the Content Blocks aren't changed, there shouldn't be issues with moving to a new folder or changing the folder name. Right?

Comment: ContentBlockByName is the full path of the content block, so if the path changes, via moving folders, then the call is no longer accurate and will error. Buy ID and Key are fine regardless of path.